# isset and empty functions are executing code when they shouldn't be - PHP

Tags: php, session

I have just come across a problem with `isset` and `empty` in `php` with a `textarea` box.  I first test to see if the `$_POST` array contains any text.  If it does, it stores that text in the `$_SESSION` array as index `comments`.  I've just tried hitting submit with an empty textarea and instead of bypassing my conditional statement, its executing it and putting blank data in my database.

Heres the html:

```
<p class="center"><textarea placeholder="450 characters max!" rows="10" cols="50" name="message" maxlength="450"></textarea></p>
```

This executes in the script that is related to the form:

```
if (isset($_POST['message']) || !empty($_POST['message'])) {
                $_SESSION['comments'] = $_POST['message'];
            }
```

This is part of a function in another script:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['comments']) || !empty($_SESSION['comments'])) {
                $comment = $_SESSION['comments'];
                // comment_id, user_id, comments
                $sql = "INSERT into comments (user_id, comments) VALUES ('{$user_id}', '{$comment}')";
                $db -> query($sql);
            }
```

In theory there shouldn't be anything in the `$_POST` and `$_SESSION` when I leave the `textarea` blank, and therefore it should not write to the `db` later on in the process.  I have quite a few of these statements in my code which by the look of it are going to behave the same way which is not good.  When I check my `db` the `comments` field is empty, but its created a row with a `comments_id` and a `user_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check for empty. This will handle isset as well:

```
if (!empty($_POST['message'])) {
    // Process
}
```

From PHP's website: No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: Best answer, covers the most with the smallest statement. No significant performance different, either.

Comment: Better reply than mine.

Comment: Thanks Andrew - Just channged all my `if` statements to just `empty` and all works as espected :-)  According to the documentation `empty` seems to class pretty much everything as empty including integer `0`.  So I'll use this from now on!

Comment: Glad it helped. This should work well for your situation in the question and a lot of user-input checks where you don't need to distinguish between an empty string, 0, FALSE, etc..., but some situations may require a stricter check than empty.

Comment: Thanks - yes I think for my case just `empty` will be fine.  Not had the need to distinguish between different forms of emptiness.  Is it possible to give a brief example of a scenario in which this would need to be done?  Would this mean using `isset` as well as `empty`?

Comment: Hey. It will be a combination of isset and the value check. Say for example you were validating a quantity field, which could be 0. You'd check that it was set and that a value was entered like so: if (isset($_POST['quantity']) && $_POST['quantity'] !== ''). This would evaluate to true with a zero whereas empty would not.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, replace

```
if (isset($_POST['message']) || !empty($_POST['message'])) {
```

by

```
if (isset($_POST['message']) && !empty($_POST['message'])) {
```

Comment: Thanks - that seems to work now.  Like i say I have a lot of these statements so I guess I need to change all of them to `&&`.  Is it best practice to use both of these functions at the same time?

Comment: it's good practice *not* to use `empty`. it's almost never what you need. http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php . do strict comparison: `!==  ""` (with an `isset` - pre-check)

Comment: If you're truly just wanting to make sure that $_POST['message'] has a non-empty value, then you're better off just making sure it's not empty. Checking if it isset and not empty is redundant; however, as mentioned above, this could still cause issues (i.e., if someone submits a 0 for their message).